# Зачем записывать ID сессий?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Скажите, зачем записывать в БД ID сессий?

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: я например обхожусь без записи в БД ID сессий, но бывают попадаются в гугле результаты поиска типа "проблемы с записью id сессий", или на форумах каких-нибудь темы про id сессий и бд темы есть. Так вот, какая цель, зачем это использовать?

Comment: Иногда прибегают к сохранению всей сессии в БД, т.к. о максимальном размере сессии для конкретного сервера мы понятия не имеем, а вот в БД мы можем хранить сколько угодно данных. Так же идентификатор сессии можно использовать с целью привязки записи к конкретному пользователю. Да и вообще, причин сего действия может быть сколько угодно. Если кто-то что-то делает, это еще не значит, что это интересная тема для изучения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID сессий - идентификатор, который имеет абсолютную защищенность. Его никак нельзя переопределить.
Первое, что приходит на ум - логгирование сессий(зачем? для последующего вывода списка пользователей в онлайне, к примеру). Или вместо идентификатора пользователя, как это ни очевидно звучит :)

Comment: Разве нельзя взломать БД mysql и узнать id сессии админа? Тогда и переопределить можно. А если не записывать в БД инфо о сессиях, то догодаться, какое id сессии у админа - сложно, да и как переопределить, если в скрипте работы с id вообще нет (они ведь не записываются). Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: > Его никак нельзя переопределить.

Ну-у, иногда есть session fixation, например.

Comment: Есть просто идентификатор, записаный в сессию(в примере - id), а есть идентификатор сессии(PHPSESSID всегда). По нему сервер определяет, что это ваши сессии. Вот, взгляните:
Array ( [PHPSESSID] => 8a8bcbfc6d87c7f89274135a8c921ec1 [lang] => en [id] => 1 [hash] => d253ce2d827c90da09f2a08525acb8f9c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b )
Примитивно = это настолько важная переменная, что php не даст её переопределить.

Comment: просто я вот не понимаю. как в таком вот коде:


<pre>session_start(); echo 'Привет '.$_SESSION['user'];</pre>

Можно переопределить сессию..?

Comment: Это признание, что Вы понятия не имеете, что такое сессия?

Comment: @nick777, взломать то можно, но это даст шанс только на время жизни сессии. Не прибавляет оно уязвимости, если руки не кривые :-)

В любом случае чтобы идентифицировать пользователя а тем более пользователя в конкретный момент времени нужен уникальны айдюк - почему не воспользоватся айдюком сессии?

Comment: @Равнодушный может и не знает, это повод ёрничать? 
Если знаете - напишите, мне тоже интересно как вы будете ломать данный скрипт - да, я не знаю как это сделать, это признание, если вам от этого легче

Comment: @zippp, сессии "ломать" никто не будет. Задача обычно сводится к перехвату идентификатора сессии, который хранится либо в куках, либо в url'е. Как "стащить" ID сессии - это отдельная интересная тема, а подставить его очень даже легко - либо в куки, либо в url. Как с этим бороться - сами додумаетесь, все элементарно.

А вопрос про знание материала напросился сам - @nick777 задаёт вопросы, которых у него не должно возникать, если имеются хоть какие-то представления как сессии хранятся и работают.